# Js script now being accessed inside modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I added an audio player inside my modal (using this code examples: https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/ascensus/419481#html-tab-view) but it's not playing inside the modal. All the audio players outside the modal works.

It looks like the js isn't being accessed once the modal is open. How do I connect the js script inside the modal?

Comment: check for errors in the browser developer tools console

Comment: can you put your code that we can check it ?

Comment: `using this code example` - well, the code example isn't going to produce your problem ... your code produces your problem, and without your code, there is no way to answer

Comment: I got it working now. Thanks everyone!